# Is an element in "hidden" display is loaded on the navigator window?

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering if an element in a hidden display still take part of the memory of the page which is loaded.

It's a very convenient way to put a lot of things on the page, but if for example we put a hundred things one above the other, with 99 elements in hidden mode and 1 element in display mode, I wonder if that is ok or not. I mean if the loaded page take in charge only the element in display mode (and then the others when we put them in a display mode too), or if it takes all the elements in charge (where the page would be too much heavy to load).

Thank you if you know more than me about that.

Comment: Short answer is it is better to only render what is needed at a given time. Overall question is far too broad though based on guidelines in the [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are on the page. In fact, you can access them via javascript. Here is an example:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test").innerHTML)
```

```html
<p id="test" hidden> Test </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have actually written code for the elements, it will be part of the memory. Remember that the CSS is loaded after the web elements.

Answer (score 0):

It will take all the elements in charge and the page will become too much heavy to load.